# Python - Adding text column to DataFrame using file paths

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have the following dataframe:

| file_path | file_name |
| --- | --- |
| /Users/user/Dropbox/SEC investigat... | _0000886982_18795_2687.txt |
| /Users/user/Dropbox/SEC investigat... | _0001068875_16706_4152.txt |
| ... | ... |

Each file_path corresponds to a specific text file. I am trying to create a new column that uses the file_path variable to create a new variable consisting of the text included in the corresponding file_path. So far, I have the following code but am getting an error (TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Series):

```
pd_00['text'] = open(pd_00['file_path'], 'r')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` to run a function on every element in a column~

```
def open_file(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        return f.read()

df['text'] = df['file_path'].apply(open_file)
```

Comment: Quick note, if there are many files it might be worth using a multithreaded approach to read the files in parallel (in this case, not with `apply`). +1

Comment: [pandarallel](https://pypi.org/project/pandarallel/)'s `parallel_apply` would probably work just fine~

Answer (score 0):

First, create a function that reads a file and returns its content:

```
def read(filename):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    return f.read()
```

Then you can use it with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

`df['content'] = df.file_name.apply(read)`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion-- I found it to be helpful.